# SMB connection with java

Tags: protocols, smb

Hi i have created a test program to connect with SMB protocol. My motive is to create a test.txt file on a shared location like `String path="smb://192.168.143.134/rtf2xml/"+sharedFolder+"/test.txt";`

But when I try to run my program (below is the code sample)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String user = "abc";
        String pass ="123456";

        String sharedFolder="INPUT";
        String path="smb://192.168.143.134/rtf2xml/"+sharedFolder+"/test.txt";
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("192.168.143.134",user, pass);
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
        smbFile.createNewFile();
        SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
        smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
        System.out.println("completed ...nice !");
    }

}
```

It is throwing exception

```
Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to negotiate
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Timeout trying to open socket
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jcifs.netbios.NbtSocket.<init>(NbtSocket.java:59)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.run(SmbTransport.java:342)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.start(SmbTransport.java:315)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate0(SmbTransport.java:865)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:941)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:827)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:797)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:852)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.createNewFile(SmbFile.java:2265)
    at Test.main(Test.java:22)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:947)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:827)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:797)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:852)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.createNewFile(SmbFile.java:2265)
    at Test.main(Test.java:22)
```

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

1. But l think you have to make sure that the destination server(192.168.143.134) is up and alive.
2. you can write it the following way, since the IP in included in the smb link.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String user = "abc";
   String pass ="123456";

   String sharedFolder="INPUT";
   String path="smb://192.168.143.134/rtf2xml/"+sharedFolder+"/test.txt";
   NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);//note here
   SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
   smbFile.createNewFile();
   SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
   smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
   System.out.println("completed ...nice !");
   ```

   }
   ....